# Can I use "write in smalls" like "write in capitals"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I know "capital" can mean "uppercase" as a noun and an adjective.
I know "small" can mean "lowercase" as an adjective.
I searched for examples of using "small" as a noun meaning "lowercase", but I couldn't find any.

Would you tell me if I can use "small" as a noun like "write in smalls"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not idiomatic.  You can say "write in lowercase", or "Don't write in capitals".

The default way of writing is to use lowercase for most letters, so normally you don't have to say anything.  Using "small" (as an adjective) should be avoided as it causes confusion: <sub><sup>IS THIS WRITTEN IN SMALL LETTERS?</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using "smalls" with that meaning, it is not idiomatic.

Comment: This answer does not seem to expand on or improve on the [earlier answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/331239/91457) by James K. It also does not cite any source or give any reasons. Those are not always required, but they do usually improve an answer.